# Shutdown Windows Server and the corresponding machine

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have read that `shutdown -s` in Windows Server only shuts down Windows. I don't know exactly what this means, but how can I shutdown *and power off* the whole machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `shutdown -s` doesn't power down your machine you'll have to physically power it off or get in with some form of remote admin tool (like HP's iLO) and send a power down command.

Most servers nowadays, though, will power down with a shutdown.

Comment: It's an old server, I want to be prepared:)Does it matter if I do shutdown -s and push the power button?

Comment: @DarkFire21 Might want to be prepared to push the Off button, then.  Push the power button once you get the "Windows is not shutdown, you can turn off your machine" message on the screen.

Comment: Ok, so I run the command and when the above message appears I push the power button.Sorry for my noobiness but it's the first I have to administer such an important machine, alla alone.thanks:)

Comment: @DarkFirew21 No need to apologize, that's why we're here :)

Comment: Oh, and the above should read "Windows is NOW shutdown, you can...."  Oops

Comment: It's been most then 10 years since I've seen a server not power off. Bios has to support APCI and you need an ATX style power supply. both have been around for 12+ years. even NT 4.0 can down a box...  The question we should ask is why do you have to power down this server?

Answer (score 1):

shutdown -s is the same as doing Start>Shutdown. It takes a REALLY old server to require you to also hit the power button after Windows is shutdown. If your server is that old, it probably total junk.